# subscriptesd value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c++

I try to distribute the companies by months according to their value.

```
void obtener_distribucion_por_meses(empresaibex t_empresasibex[],int total_empresas, int mes_actual){
    int i,valoresmes;
      for(i=0;i<mes_actual;i++){
            valoresmes[i]=aleatorio;
      }
}
```

Comment: `valoresmes` is an `int`. `i` is an `i`. This `valoresmes[i]` should maybe be `t_empresasibex[i]`, its the only array in sight

Comment: `aleatorio` is not declared and `total_empresas` is unused, maybe more typos

Answer (score 1):

Since this is non-english, I can't exactly understand what you're trying, but you can't access to `valoresmes`, which is an int, with an index. Maybe you  were trying to do it with your array `t_empresasibex` ?